# What is a printer console/terminal?

Tags: g-code, software, knowledgebase, usb

I read that G-code commands can be sent through a console/terminal over USB. What is a console/terminal and how do you use that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several programs that could serve as a console to connect to a printer, put let's start somewhere: the USB connection.

## Step 1: Connection with USB

When connecting the printer via USB for the first time, we will get a notification that some unknown item is connected. If we use windows we can learn what device it decided we now have via the `device manager` (`Windows Key` then typing in `manager` and `Enter`). It should be a COM Port as this picture shows.

[image: Windows Device Manager]

In this case, we have connected to **`COM4`**. To change the COM port, we can do so via a `Rightclick`->`properties`, then the `connection settings` and `advanced`. In the new window, we can change the COM port number to anything from 1 to 256, but it is recommended to keep the number somewhat low.

Make sure you run the printer's power supply **and** the connection via USB, as you can't use motor control commands if you have the power supply for the printer off.

## Step 2: Using the COM-port

Now, we need a program that can use the COM port to connect to the printer. There are, as said, several out there. One such is **[Repetier Host](https://www.repetier.com/)**, which comes with slicer and a good graphical interface. Another is **[Ultimaker Cura](https://ultimaker.com/software/ultimaker-cura)**, which has the same capacities but lacks logging of all the commands exchanged. Because many are familiar with it as a slicer, I will look at it first. As a third option, I will take a look at **[Pronterface](https://www.pronterface.com/)**.

CAVEAT: Only **one** program that actively uses the COM port can be properly run at the same time, as the first program accessing the port will claim all uses for the COM port till it is shut down - any program or even other instances of the same program trying to access the port after that will have no control of the port.

### Ultimaker Cura

After launching Ultimaker Cura, choose your printer. many printers are available as presets by now, so just import the printer you use or make a custom profile. At the moment the latest version of Cura is 4.1.0, and will look like this:

[image: Cura GUI: Top toolbar]

After switching to `Monitor`, it will automatically connect to the Printer via the COM port, in my case 4.

[image: Cura GUI: Monitor Interface]

Once more we test the connection via Home [image: Home Cura] and then use the Send G-Code prompt, confirming lines via `Enter`.

[image: Cura GUI: G-code Prompt]

### Repetier Host

After running Repetier Host the first time, you need to configure your printer. `Ctrl`+`P` opens the config window for the printer. We need to know the Baud Rate of our printer, so I looked up the documentation of my Ender3, which told me 115200 is the right setting. Most printers seem to run on this setting. The other tabs decide the speeds, extruder number and limits and the bed shape. The rest isn't needed for this. My settings for the Ender3 are these:
[image: Repetier GUI: Connection Tab] [image: Repetier GUI: Printer Tab][image: Repetier GUI: Extruder Tab][image: Repetier GUI: Printer Shape Tab]

Ok, we made our settings and saved via `OK`.

Now, we press the Connect button on the left side of the menu:

[image: Repetier GUI: Disconnected left side menu]

It should change to the blue Disconnect button and display other parts of the print now, showing that we have connected. Note that at the bottom of the screen a log is filled with all the commands and exchanges.

[image: Repetier Host GUI: Connected left side menu]
[image: Repetier Host Log snipped - very detailed]

On the right side, we now can choose the Tab `Manual Control`
[image: Repetier Host: Right side of Interface]

Before sending any commands, it is a good idea to press the Home [image: Home] button. This also serves as an extra test to see if the printer is connected correctly. Now we can use the Prompt G-Code to send our commands. The commands will be put into the log below.

[image: send G-Code line]
[image: Repetier Log]

### Pronterface

This is the first time that I used [Pronterface](https://www.pronterface.com/). The first thing to do after downloading the Printrun package and running the Pronterface application is to press `Port`, then set the right Baudrate (115200 seems to work for many machines) and press `connect`.

[image: Pronterface GUI extract: connect button]

The GUI will saturate and the right log will show lots of things tested in connection. Note that in the lower right of the GUI, there is a temperature curve log, which can be very handy for troubleshooting, as it shows the change over a little time.

[image: Pronterface GUI extract: after connecting]
[image: Pronterace Log]

Below the log, we find the input for commands, and if we send a command, we get a log entry of it:

[image: Pronterface Lower Right Command Prompt]

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/10574/5740), the OctoPrint 3D print server software contains a terminal which you can use to send G-code commands from a browser:

### OctoPrint

In the bottom string input box (under the check mark items) you put in a G-code command, which will be send to the printer when you hit the *Send* button. If the printer gives a reply to that command, it will be displayed in the log window above the check mark interface items.

[image: OctoPrint terminal interface]