# Ender3 V2: What stops the Y?

Tags: creality-ender-3, endstop

As there is no limit switch on the operator end of the Y (Y-), what stops its travel when the print is done?

Answer (score 1):

There only need to be one physical endstop on each axis, if the printer has the dimensions of the printer programmed in.

The Ender3 has its dimensions defined in the firmware, so once homed and then moved to 0 (the end stop and 0 can be different!), the printer won't move willingly out of the orthogonal-space that is positioned between $$\matrix {0\\0\\0} \to\matrix{maxX\\ maxY\\ maxZ}$$.

Where these are can be manipulated with the right software, as the printer in running operation takes the values from the EEPROM - which can be directly altered by for example a [terminal akin to Repetier Host.](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10573/what-is-a-printer-console-terminal)

Comment: Concur.  The enders have an optional Z extension kit which comes with longer rails and a replacement leadscrew.  The only config change to extend Z is in software.   Also notice that there isn't an end-switch on X or Z, just the stepper motors keeping track of steps forward and backward.

Comment: @Criggie you can alter the software endstop via the EEPROM - till the moment you overwrite with firmware defaults, yes.