# Adjust E-step on Ender 3

Tags: creality-ender-3, extruder, stepper

I was getting some weird under extrusion and noticed that the gear on the extruder was a bit worn.

I decided to replace it with a dual-drive extruder, but that makes the E-step way off. I tried to run 100 mm through without any PTFE tube and only got 67 mm.

I am trying to figure out where I need to change the number.

I have the 4.2.7 motherboard, and I also put on the Creality touch screen.

It doesn't seem to have any place to enter those settings that I can find.

Comment: Which firmware are you using and what version?

Comment: @agarza according to the screen on the printer, it's version 2.0.1.4, and I put on the firmware that goes with the touch screen and cr touch bed level sensor

Comment: If you are using the Marlin firmware, 0scar's answer will work for you. If you are using something different, i.e. Jyers' UI, that firmware will store the setting in EEPROM.

Comment: @agarza I'm using the stock firmware, so Marlin I assume. It looks like Jyers is for the Ender-3 V2, and I have the original, though I did upgrade the motherboard to the 4.2.7 so I could put on a CR-Touch... Will it work for me?

Comment: You should be fine with the CR Touch. It is Creality's own product so there shouldn't be any problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no interface to set the value through the display, you can always set the E-steps per G-code.

> [`M92`](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M92:_Set_axis_steps_per_unit) **Set axis_steps_per_unit**

There are at least 2 options, the first is to connect a USB cable and connect to a console ([What is a printer console/terminal?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10573/what-is-a-printer-console-terminal)) or second "print" the applicable G-codes by creating a text file (with a `.gcode`/`.g` file extension) and place the `M92 E139` on the first line and `M500` on the second line. The latter option requires you to print the file once as it stores the new E-steps value.

---

*E.g. the current value for the Ender 3 is 93 which gives you 67 mm, to get to 100 mm you would need: $\displaystyle \frac{93\times100}{67} \approx 139$ steps, so `M92 E139` would set a new value. Store the value with `M500`. Note that this board stores the settings on the SD card as it has no EEPROM, so have an SD card present in the slot of the board! If you're unable to store the value you can also put it in the start G-code of the slicer, but that is not a preferred method.*