# Ender 3 Pro, tried both SKR Mini E3 V2 and V3 and still unable to connect with OctoPrint

Tags: creality-ender-3, octoprint, skr-mini-e3

So, long story short, I was using the SKR Mini E3 V2 and had a load of weird issues which lead to it not being able to connect via a Raspberry Pi 3B via USB (using OctoPi distribution).

I tried updating firmware and it would connect to the printer but failed whenever I did anything i.e. heating, moving an axis, etc. I eventually managed to find a heating error. I changed the thermistor on the hot end, realized it was complaining about the heated bed so changed that too, then the Pi just wouldn't see the board. I bought a new V3 board and on the first test everything connected fine; it even started heating up and then cut off as it was getting warm. After a couple of attempts to refresh the firmware, it has done the same thing where it won't find the printer. Like an idiot, I had removed the original LCD screen as I would just use OctoPrint as the screen. I am going to check it when I find out what I did with it.

Firstly, is there a way to set the boards back to default, just so the Pi sees either again? Secondly, is there a reasonable firmware that I can download or should I just use the Visual Studio application to rebuild the firmware? Would this even be helpful at this stage?

Comment: First thing you should try is to see if you can establish a connection to the controller boards over USB (beware of Baud rate and USB port location/name). Use Pronterface or other [console interface](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10573/) and try to manage the printer from your computer/laptop. If that works, OctoPrint should also work, we may need some screenshots of the connection and the failures shown by OctroPrint.

Answer (score 1):

Well.... turns out I'm kind of an idiot but not entirely... I found 3dprintscape.com and he said he had issues with the firmware downloading directly but if he downloaded the whole git as a zip and got it from there... I tried it and it seems to have worked! I even found my screen for the printer which confirms it... but that now means I have an extra board which is probably working fine... dammit... lol

Thanks for at least looking at it if you did... sorry to be easily confused..