# Z-Offset Multiple Heads on Tool Change

Tags: marlin, ultimaker-cura, extruder, z-probe

I have created my own tool changer for my 3D Printer but I'm having an issue with the Z-offset for each head.

- **Firmware:** Marlin 2.1
- **Slicer:** Cura

I have used the offset wizard to get the Z-offset of each head from the bed and then I tried to use the following G-code (`M851 Z-4.3`) in the Extruder Start G-Code and I have done this for each head, I can see it has changed on the screen in the configuration menu but it looks like it has had no effect as the print has already started.

What is the best way for me to set each offset for all my extruders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a specific code to set the offset between the various tools. This G-code is called [`M218` - Set Hotend Offset](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M218.html).

[image]

Comment: @0scar, how is it possible to "view the current hotend offsets with M503"? Where I can read this result value? Here there is an explanation: https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M503.html, but currently is beyond my knowledge...

Comment: This may help you understand: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10573/what-is-a-printer-console-terminal