# How to see BLTouch probing results?

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling, bltouch

How do I view the results from the BLTouch probing on my Ender 3?

I have set up all the firmware and installed the BLTouch fine and it works as expected. But how am I able to see the results of the `G29` 9-step probes so I can view them in a mesh visualiser?

I don’t have an OctoPrint print server, as I know this comes with a Plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

G-code [`M420 V`](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M420.html) will show the mesh heights of the currently loaded mesh.

You can use a [console](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10573/what-is-a-printer-console-terminal) to send the command and retrieve the values.

Answer (score -1):

I used Pronterface terminal emulator and connected the printer via USB! Simple really when you figure out how!

Comment: It would be beneficial to future readers as to **how** using Proterface can provide the information in the original question. You can get additional information on [how to write a good answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help Center.

Comment: Please [edit] and explain how. It is great that you have solved your problem, but it would be helpful to other users with the same issue to know the steps that you took.