# Ender-3 Pro Factory reset/BLTouch Setup

Tags: creality-ender-3, bltouch, lcd-screen, reset

I bought the BLTouch and followed the instructions to install it, but it ended up not working. After installing the new firmware, the screen started bugging out (pixels being out of place, always moving). And when I tried to use the BLTouch, it didn't detect anything below it; the light is always red, and the plastic part it uses to sense doesn't move and making my printer unusable.

I looked online to see how to reset my printer so I could re-install the software, but it mentioned a terminal and I didn't understand what that was. My computer runs Windows 11, and I'm fairly new to PCs, so a step-by-step would be helpful.

Comment: [What is a printer console/terminal?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10573/what-is-a-printer-console-terminal).