# Cura does not connect to Sovol SV04

Tags: ultimaker-cura, usb, serial-connection

I followed the instruction [here](https://community.ultimaker.com/topic/41296-cura-for-sovol-sv04/) and [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/10574) and I'm trying to connect my Sovol SV04 with Cura in order to enable the "Monitor" page.

When I connect the USB cable, Ubuntu 22.04 creates the serial port. I'm able to open it with a serial terminal and to send G-Code commands. The printer acts according.

But when I try to open the Monitor page in Cura 5.2.2 it just says it cannot find the printer:

[image]

but without any error message or other useful information.
What am I missing here?

Comment: As you are using Ubuntu, some of the information in the second link isn't useful, as it's windows focused. Have you determined the USB identifier and confirmed that it is the same one selected in Cura? I think yes to the former, as you can send g-code, but perhaps no to the latter?

Comment: @fred_dot_u how can I check the USB id selected in Cura? I don't see anything related to the USB connection

Comment: Apparently such a useful feature isn't part of Cura! I did find this posting on reddit that may be of value: https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprinting/comments/klfu5u/how_to_enable_usb_printing_via_cura_on_ubuntu/